# How to insert if not exists with selecting from same table?

Tags: mysql, database, h2, insert-query

I have my table schema in H2 db as follows:

**create table if not exists Test ( id bigint not null,name varchar(255), primary key (id) );**

**alter table Test add constraint if not exists Test_NAME UNIQUE (name);**

I want to insert a value for the name attribute as 'Default' if it does not exist in the table by selecting the latest id value from the table and increment it by one.

**Example:**
Do not insert if an entry for name = Default already exists.

ID     | Name

1      | Default

Insert if an entry for name = Default does not exists.

ID     | Name

1      | ABC

2      | XYZ

For the id column, find the max id and increment it by one. In this case, insert id=3 and name=Default.

My query is as follows:

**INSERT INTO Test (id , name)
    SELECT max(id) + 1, 'Default' from Test
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Test where name='Default');**

However, it gives me an error saying: 
NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement
as it applies the where condition on the inner select statement.

I also tried:
**MERGE INTO Test KEY(name) VALUES (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 from Test, 'Default');**

It gives an error because, merge tries to update with the new values. 
If it finds 'Default', it will update the row with new id causing primary key violation.

Is there a better way to do this? How can I make the query work?

Answer (score 3):

You are massively overcomplicating this. Define the `id` field as [auto increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) and place a unique index on the `name` field. The unique index prevents duplicate names to be inserted, while the auto increment increases the value of the id field by 1 (by default) if the insert is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I updated id to auto increment and the following query work flawlessly

> INSERT INTO Test (name) select * from (select 'Default') as tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name from Test where name='Default');

Answer (score 0):

when you run your query first time, no record found in table so, it give error 'null' there, so if you add IFNULL() function there as below

```
INSERT INTO Test (id , name) 
SELECT **IFNULL**(max(id),0) + 1, 'Default' 
FROM Test 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Test where name='Default');
```